# how to resolve "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

conf like :

```html
http {
    upstream lb{
        server directory_back1:8000;
        server directory_back2:8000;
        server directory_back3:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name df.dotapp.app;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://directory_front:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name db.dotapp.app;;

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://lb;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me the following:

> nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in
> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

what am I gonna do?

Comment: where is the rest of your nginx config? you're missing the `user`, `worker_processes`, `error_log`, `pid` directives, etc. Is this file an include your showing here, if so you may have put a `http` inside a `http` directive.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.